# Ace Editor - multiple word highlight rule

Tags: javascript, regex, syntax-highlighting, highlighting, ace-editor

This is going to be a very picky question i'm afraid - and I have a feeling it will not be possible.

#### Situation

I need to have a textarea with highligting (Some css effect) of certain words and phrases.
Previously I have got this working with editarea - however as it is a dead project more and more issues arose so I am trying an alternate more current editor - Ace.

#### Issue

I currenty have ace highlighting the sets of single words fine using a custom mode, however matching with the regex the phrases has proven beyond me (so far).

The relevant mode code - as it stands is below:

```
var highlightWords = "word1|word2|word3|phrase one|phrase number two|etc";
 var keywordMapper = this.createKeywordMapper({
     "highlightWords": highlightWords
}, "identifier", true);

this.$rules = {
    "start" : [
    {
        token : keywordMapper,
        regex : "[a-zA-Z0-9_$][a-zA-Z0-9_$]*\\b"
    },{
        token : "text",
        regex : "\\s+"
    }]
```

My attempt to match 2 word phrases is below (Didn't work) (Also attempted to match longer entries by adding coppies with {2} etc)

```
regex : "[a-zA-Z0-9_$][a-zA-Z0-9_$]*(?:\\s[a-zA-Z0-9_$][a-zA-Z0-9_$]*){1}\\b"
```

Anybody have any ideas for getting ace working - or any easier alternatives for live edit word & phrase highlighting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The regex you are passing to keywordMapper doesn't match space character.

use

```
this.$rules = {
    "start" : [
    {
        token : "highlightWords",
        regex : "word1|word2|word3|phrase one|phrase number two|etc"
    }]
}
```

Comment: Now this is odd (/Annoying at self) as plugging the same regex was one of the first tricks I tried - with no luck.
However I have just tried it again and I guess some of my other code prevented it from working at first, as it now works perfectly.
Anyway cheers

Comment: Sorry to ask another question - but as this is more of a bolt on, I will anyway.

I need to make the regex case insensitive - normally not an issue just add the i flag, however it somehow seems to be ignored/overwritten by ace, (Or am I just missing something), Current code:  `regex: new RegExp(lower_words_regex,"gi")`

Comment: @Olirav you could add an inline `i` flag in your regex like this `/(?i)your_regex/`

Comment: Seemed a great idea (Hadn't heard of the inline modes until now)  however it appears JavaScript doesn't support them?

Comment: javascript doesn't support inline flags. but you can add `caseInsensitive:true` flag to the rule see
https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/master/lib/ace/mode/css_highlight_rules.js#L89
https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/master/lib/ace/tokenizer.js#L64

Comment: Great that seems to work perfectly, Cheers - Saved me some time too, I was just starting the great trawl through the source code to try find that very point. Thanks